# Self hosted web api on windows service permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, permissions, windows-services, self-hosting

I am hosting Web Api in my windows service, and I have an issue with starting the Web Api Service from windows service, this is the exception that I get as I debug it:

> System.AggregateException occurred    HResult=-2146233088    Message=One or more errors occurred.    Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          ....   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146233087
>          Message=HTTP could not register URL http://+:1243/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
>          Source=System.ServiceModel.Internals
>          ......

If I'm hosting the same Web Service in a console application, everything works. How can I set permissions for my windows service to launch a web service?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: it's probably something related to current user: when you run the console application, current user it's you (and maybe you have "hight" privileges. When running the service, user is someone else (usually LocalService or NetworkService)

Comment: Yes, my service runs as LocalService Account, but I don't want to change its account to User - cause then the User will need to enter the creadentials each time the process runs...Is there a way to set those "high" privileges to the service which runs under LocalService Account?

Comment: that's not true: you are not able to specify username and password when the service starts, you have to set it up using e.g. controlPanel->services->Properties->Connection.
But I would not use a real user anyway, it would give more problems than benefit. e.g., when the user change its password, the service would not be able to start.
Try with a different built-in users (maybe Network service has enogh privilege for what you need)

Comment: Changing to NetworkService service didn't helped either, still getting this exception as I start the service... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike hosting under IIS (which deals with this for you), when self-hosting you'll need to create an ACL for the URL you are listening on, for the user you are running as. Something like this (from a privileged command line):-

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:1234/ user=LocalService
```

I've not tried the above with LocalService specifically, but this is required when listening on anything other than localhost.

More info available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx)